# Where to get free data set for sparse system of linear equations?

Tags: parallel-processing, sparse-matrix, gaussian, linear-equation

I am trying to parallelize gaussian elimination on sparse linear equations. I could not find data to test any where on the internet. If you could provide links to such data set that will be great.

Also could someone please explain how are sparse linear equations produced, that is practically, what problems produce such equations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering if you even did any own research-attempt. (1) Please read SO's rules. This is off-topic. (2) Start with [SuiteSparse Matrix Collection](https://sparse.tamu.edu/) (3) Apart from the applications mentioned in the linked collection, nearly every numerical-optimization algorithm wastes much of his time solving sparse linear systems (core ingredient!).

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says you cannot ask us to recommend or find off-site resources. We are also not personal research assistants.

Answer (score 0):

### First:

If indeed interested in linear problem sparse matrices, you may enjoy datasets from almost any linear Finite Element Method problem formulation.

Their problem-formulation may still use a vast amount of just linear equations.

Their problem-space is principally sparse in 3D-sense, so even if the original data were not represented as sparse-matrices, you can easily convert any of their dense-matrix representation into any sparse-matrix representation of your choice.

[image]

### Next:

There are [**further sources**](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/browse.html) of further interest for dense & sparse array I/O using the [**Matrix Market** format](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html)